# Android programmatically created MapView v2 is not displayed

Tags: android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I updated RawMapViewDemoActivity.java in the Android Google Maps v2 sample app to programmatically create a MapView but map is not displayed. I just get a blank screen.

I replaced

```
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
```

with

```
    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
    options.camera(new CameraPosition(new LatLng(0, 0), 15, 0, 0));         
    mMapView = new MapView(this, options);
    mMapView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors being logged anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Have you forwarded all the livecycle methods to the new `MapView`?

```
mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Take a look at the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)

Comment: Greeny, thanks for the reply. Yes, I used the source from the sample app that forwards all the livecycle methods. I think it may be a simple layout issue. I'll keep digiging.

Comment: Have you added the MapView to the layout after creating it with `mMapView = new MapView(this, options);`?  
  
Try `setContentView(mMapView)`

Comment: Thanks gain Greeny but this didn't do it. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I fixed this a while ago, but forgot to post the answer.

It seems that a MapView must be placed in a layout container before it will be correctly displayed. The following snippet shows what I did to make the sample work.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.camera(new CameraPosition(new LatLng(0, 0), 1, 0, 0));          
mMapView = new MapView(this, options);
linearLayout.addView(mMapView);
setContentView(linearLayout);
```